# E.CalView Usage in Vala

Tags: c++, calendar, vala

I'm trying to use the EDS (Evolution Data Server) to create a application to show calendar events for a specific day. I'm using vala to write the code.

I guess that I need to make use of the library here: `http://valadoc.org/#!api=libecalendar-1.2/E.CalView`

However, I'm not able to get started:

```
public class CalTest {
  public static int main (string[] args) {
    print("start");
    unowned E.CalClientView ccv = CalClientView.get_client ();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Throws an error:

> test.vala:3.9-3.9: error: The symbol `E' could not be found.

The compile command used is:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg granite test.vala
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile the application?

Comment: @apmasell compile command: valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg granite test.vala

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile including the package containing this namespace: `--pkg libecalendar-1.2`

It will also require the C development package be installed. It's `evolution-data-server-dev` on Debian and Ubuntu, and `evolution-data-server-devel` on Fedora.

Comment: Many thanks for the support. I installed evolution-data-server-dev and changed the compile command to valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg granite --pkg libecalendar-1.2 "test.vala". However, it still gives the error: error: Package `libecalendar-1.2' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories. I guess I'm close, probably missing a pointer at some file or directory ?

Comment: The package is apparently called `libecal1.2-dev` as is the pkg-config file `libecal-1.2.pc`.

Comment: It seems that the vapi file `libecalendar-1.2.vapi` was removed from the libecal package with GNOME 3.10 (3.8 still had it, see for example http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libecal1.2-dev/filelist )

Comment: https://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-data-server/commit/vala/Makefile.am?h=gnome-3-10&id=510b1f7c85a94b1c6a51f54e1cb2d45cad207d7b

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Many thanks, I will try your suggestion and see if it lets me compile